# Equivalent of Custom Script Extensions for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, azure-vm

What is the equivalent of [Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) (for Azure VM's) in AWS world?

Comment: Is it simply running a script on a VM? Sounds similar to [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html).

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the way. Thanks.